# Why is my long polling code for a notification system not updating in real time? PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, long-polling

I am making a notification system similar to the red notification on facebook.  It should update the number of messages sent to a user in real time.  When the message MYSQL table is updated, it should instantly notify the user, but it does not.  There does not seem to be an error inserting into MYSQL because on page refresh the notifications update just fine.

I am essentially using code from this video tutorial: http://www.screenr.com/SNH (which updates in realtime if a data.txt file is changed, but it is not written for MYSQL like I am trying to do)

Is there something wrong with the below code:

```
**Javascript**

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   

var timestamp = null;
function waitForMsg(){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "getData.php",
    data: "userid=" + userid,
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
        var json = eval('(' + data + ')');
        if (json['msg'] != "") {

            $('.notification').fadeIn().html(json['msg']);
        }

        setTimeout('waitForMsg()',30000);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
        setTimeout('waitForMsg()',30000);
    }
});
}

waitForMsg();
</script>
<body>
<div class="notification"></div>


**PHP***

<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' )
{

$userid = $_GET['userid'];
include("config.php");

$sql="SELECT MAX(time) FROM notification WHERE userid='$userid'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$currentmodif = $row['MAX(time)'];

$s="SELECT MAX(lasttimeread) FROM notificationsRead WHERE submittedby='$userid'";
$r = mysql_query($s);
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
$lasttimeread = $rows['MAX(lasttimeread)'];


while ($currentmodif <= $lasttimeread) {
usleep(10000);
clearstatcache();
$currentmodif = $row['MAX(time)'];
}

$response = array();    

$response['msg']       = You have new messages;
echo json_encode($response);

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a problem with your javascript line below

```
  url: "getData.php",
    data: "userid" + userid,
    async: true,
```

remove the = sign and try again.

i have not read the whole code but found this is the cause test and feel free to reply if still got more issues.

Comment: removing the = sign does not seem to do anything in the right direction.  in fact the notifications no longer update upon refresh like they did with the = sign.

Comment: $currentmodif = $row['MAX(time)'];
what is the value returned by the mysql i think $currentmodif is wrong can also paste the print_r of db results as well. Also console.log of data received on success for better understanding

Comment: $row['MAX(time)'] is the highest unix time of all messages.  An notification should show if the $currentmodif time is higher than $lasttimeread (which is updated into MYSQL every time a check message button is clicked).

Comment: @Mian_Khurram_ljaz,  Thanks for your help.  The console log reads the following when a message is sent:  [19-Mar-2012 23:59:58] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in getData.php on line 24 (Above code: "while ($currentmodif <= $lasttimeread) {")

[20-Mar-2012 00:00:26] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in getData.php on line 25 (Above code: ("usleep(10000);")

Comment: ah :) so now you know what was the cause . :)

Comment: well, now I know what cause i need to google next, but i still don't know what to do.  i'm relatively new to php/mysql.  any suggestions?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9069/discussion-between-mian-khurram-ijaz-and-tjones)

Answer (score 0):

You're not re-executing the SQL statement in the loop so the value in "$row['MAX(time)']" is never going to change.

If you re-execute the query in the loop this example may work--but executing a query every 10ms is not going to be a very efficient way to implement real-time notification.

Also, if the PHP script runs longer then the time configured in php.ini (max_execution_time, 30 secs by default), you'll get an error.

Comment: The script apparently did run longer than the time configured.  So i put the query into a loop. and it did not appear to change behavior.  Although, I did some debugging w/o the loop and it appears if i alert $row['MAX(time)'} after someone posts a new message, i can get the $row['MAX(time)'].  Second, can you tell me how i could make a more efficient real-time notification given my code above?

Comment: How many clients are you trying to support?  If it's a small number then perhaps this approach will work--although you'll need to put a time limit on the server request (i.e. have the php return a different message if there is nothing available in a minute).
To scale to a large number of users you'll probably need a more "push-friendly" server technology--for example, I use node.js and socket.io to push events.

Comment: thanks for the tips.  i'm a noob, so node and socket seem like they perform the same functions (thought socket seems to advertise that it works for mobile apps too).  do you have a good reason to have a preference for either?

Comment: The socket.io project has a client and server side; the server side runs on node.js.  There are other socket.io servers (such as tornadio or gevent-socketio) and other comet implementations to choose from.  The common thread is an asynchronous server framework that can handle ajax long polling efficiently.